# Docker-compose MySQL container access from another container

Tags: c#, mysql, docker, docker-compose, entity-framework-core

I am relatively new to docker and I'm trying to create a development environment my C# project with a MySQL server and database.

I already have my C# console project Dockerfile and also a docker-compose file that has a service to my project and a service for a MySQL server. The problem is, from my C# console project, I can't access the MySQL server from that container using the service name or the `container_name` if set.

There is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  databasetester:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}databasetester
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/DatabaseTester/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
      MYSQL_USER: testusr
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testpwd
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testroot
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    expose:
      - 3307
    volumes:
      - ./bin/_database:/var/lib/mysql
```

Also, in my project I am using EntityFrameworkCore to access the database:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CharacterEntity> Characters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql("Server=db;Uid=testusr;Pwd=testpwd;Database=testdb;Port=3307");

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class CharacterEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I start the project, it throws an error while trying to connect to the mysql server:

> An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

I tried to follow many tutorials and guides and they are all using the service name has a "server" in the mysql connection string, but in my case it doesn't seem to work.

Do you have any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Try to change your connection to ```optionsBuilder.UseMySql("Server=db;Uid=testusr;Pwd=testpwd;Database=testdb;Port=3306")```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

You should change the port of connection string to `3306` because when you define `"3307:3306"` the port `3307` is available from out of network and you can't access to `3307` from inside of network

```cs
 optionsBuilder.UseMySql("Server=db;Uid=testusr;Pwd=testpwd;Database=testdb;Port=3306");
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the error. I was missing the part that the exposed port was only available from out of the network. I've learn something useful today! Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Eastrall Glad I helped you ;)